# Under EASA rules, what do I need to do to be able to perform aerobatics?

Tags: easa-regulations, aerobatics, flying-in-formation

In addition to the aerobatics mentioned in the title, I would also be interested into formation flying.

Is there a specific licence to be acquired? Does a licence covers both?
What are the requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The appropriate rules are in [FCL.800 Aerobatic Rating](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/AMC%20and%20GM%20to%20Part-FCL.pdf)

- A licensed pilot may not undertake aerobatic flights unless they hold an Aerobatic **Rating**
- 40 Hours of Flight Time (or 120 launches for sailplanes as PIC) **completed after issue of respective license**
- Aerobatic Training course including theoretical knowledge and 5 hours or 20 flights
- Aerobatics must subsequently be flown in same category aircraft as used for rating
- No revalidation/renewal requirements
- Be issued a certificate of satisfactory completion of the instruction for the license **endorsement**

So there is no specific license to be obtained, however there is a specific **rating**, which is just an endorsement in your logbook.

Its not clear from the documents that I've read that formation flying qualifies as aerobatics. Some other countries don't consider formation flying an aerobatic operation.